# Use of dust.js parameters to set locale for strings in Json

Tags: dust.js

I have the following json structure:

```
{
 locale : "en",
 text {
     "en": "Hello",
     "fr": "Bonjour"
 }
}
```

I want to pick up the locale in my template and use it when accessing the text.  I thought something like this might work:

```
{#text foo=locale}
    {text.foo}
{/text}
```

But I get nothing.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the LinkedIn fork of Dust, you can simply do `{text[locale]}`. I tested this in the LinkedIn playground [here](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html).

Comment: I knew it must be simple but just couldn't see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it in the end with a helper function.

Helper function looks something like this:

```
dust.helpers.locale = function(chunk, ctx, bodies, params){
    var locale = params.loc;
    var text = params.txt;
    return chunk.write(text[locale]);
}
```

I can then call it from the template like so:

```
{@locale loc=locale txt=text /}
```

Not sure if there is a way of doing this without the helper but this seems to work fine.